# mod_rewrite remove query string on top of a rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-task-(.*)\.html$ /index.php/task/name/$2\-task\-$1 [L]
```

When I tried to open:

```
/heru-task-number-1.html
```

It is working fine. HOwever, when there is a query string appended to it:

```
/heru-task-number-1.html?whatever=value
```

It is actually not calling the correct rewrite. Thus, I wonder how can I make sure so that both:

```
/heru-task-number-1.html
```

AND

```
/heru-task-number-1.html?whatever=value
```

are actually calling the same thing that is:

```
/index.php/task/name/$2\-task\-$1
```

I have tried to do this but to no avail.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-task-(.*)\.html\?(.*)$ /index.php/task/name/$2\-task\-$1 [L]
```

Thank you for your help or feedback on this.

Comment: works fine for me..try to use the QSA parameter or to add a interrogation mark at the end of your handling page.

Comment: Should just work. Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by inserting the following code at the top of htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fb_comment_id=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

basically, what it does is that it will remove any extra query string that has fb_comment_id and redirect 301 to the one without query string.

Thank you @oddant and @Gerben for helping out!